# Distance from a point to a line derivation

Tags: geometry

This figure is from Morris Kline's "Calculus: An Intuitive and Physical Approach". It is used to help derive the general equation for the distance from a point to a line.

[image: Distance from the point P to a line]

The book states

> We note that the given line cuts the $x$- and $y$-axes at $F$
> and $E$, respectively, and so forms the triangle $FOE$. Moreover, because $PS$ is parallel to $EO$, $\angle 1 = \angle 2 $, and **both triangles $FOE$ and $PRS$ are right triangles**. Hence the two triangles are similar

I understand why $\triangle FOE$ is a right triangle since the $x$ and $y$ axis are perpendicular. How did they conclude that triangle $PRS$ is a right triangle as well without just looking at the figure? We only know that $\triangle PRS$ and $\triangle FOE$ share one angle.

Comment: You could say $\angle PRS$ is a right angle because line $\overleftrightarrow{ RS}$ is a tangent to the circle with center $P$ and radius $d$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks! That makes sense to me.

Comment: The thing to remember is that the point $R$ at shortest distance from point P on line $(L)$ is necessarily the orthogonal projection of $P$ (if line segment $PR$ wasn't orthogonal to $(L)$, there would exist a shortcut $PR′$ with $PR′$ orthogonal to $(L)$... !